# PHP 5.4.17 alternative for the "... operator"

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.4

I was wondering if someone may know an alternative to the PHP 5.6.x and higher `...` operator (or splat operator I believe its called).

What i'm currently doing in my PHP 7 version is:

```
$this->callAction(
...explode('@', $this->routes["authControllers"][$this->routes["uri"][$uri]])
);
```

The `callAction()` function takes 2 parameters `callAction($controller, $action)` but now I need to downgrade the code to PHP 5.4.17.

Comment: PHP 5.4 is nearly two years out of support and dangerously insecure to run as a result. That said, the old approach was using http://php.net/func_get_args instead.

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look at func_get_args.
And yeah i know it has been out of support for quit a while now, but my teacher doesn't what to update his local server :/

Comment: Either explode to an array and pass `0` and `1` or use `call_user_func_array()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the splat operator `...` is similar to `call_user_func_array()`:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this,'callAction'),
                     explode('@', $this->routes["authControllers"][$this->routes["uri"][$uri]]));
```

I think it would make more sense to pass the required arguments:

```
list($controller, $action) = explode('@', $this->routes["authControllers"][$this->routes["uri"][$uri]]);
$this->callAction($controller, $action);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

i think the equivalent PHP5 code would be `call_user_func_array(array($this,'callAction'),(explode('@', $this->routes["authControllers"][$this->routes["uri"][$uri]])));`

edit: but if the callAction always takes exactly 2 arguments, you could just do

```
$args=explode('@',$this->routes["authControllers"][$this->routes["uri"][$uri]]));
$this->callAction($args[0],$args[1]);
```

but if thats the case, idk why the php7 code bothers with the `...` at all, i thought that was for variable number of arguments? (like call_user_func_array is for. for an example of a function that takes a variable number of arguments, see  `var_dump`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply