# PHP variable packing and unpacking

Tags: php, stripe-payments, packing

I have a function that is used in Stripe PHP that requires PHP 5.6. I am running it on a server that has PHP 5.5.9 and giving me some trouble. The function is:

```
protected function buildPath($basePath, ...$ids)
    {
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            if (null === $id || '' === \trim($id)) {
                $msg = 'The resource ID cannot be null or whitespace.';

                throw new \Stripe\Exception\InvalidArgumentException($msg);
            }
        }

        return \sprintf($basePath, ...\array_map('\urlencode', $ids));
    }
```

I understand that the elipses(...) means it is variable packing. but when I try to convert it to something PHP 5.5.9 can use, using the below, it does not work:

```
protected function buildPath($basePath, pack($ids))
    {
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            if (null === $id || '' === \trim($id)) {
                $msg = 'The resource ID cannot be null or whitespace.';

                throw new \Stripe\Exception\InvalidArgumentException($msg);
            }
        }

        return \sprintf($basePath, ...\array_map('\urlencode', $ids));
    }
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/294313/2943403)

Answer (score 3):

`...` in PHP can be used for two things:

- Array *unpacking*, when *calling* a function, or populating another array. Note that this is not related to the [unpack](https://www.php.net/unpack) function, which is about handling binary data, but means "turn the items of this array into separate arguments to the function", or "... separate items of the final array".
- Collecting *variadic arguments* - that is, a [variable length argument list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) - when *declaring* a function. This is close to the reverse of "unpacking", but I've never heard it called "packing". Again, the [pack](https://php.net/pack) function is completely unrelated (although, by coincidence, it is itself a variadic function). The effect is to take any number of arguments passed to the function and turn them into an array.

The example you show uses both features.

---

For the function *signature*, it is using *variadic arguments*. As noted on the manual page linked earlier:

> Note: It is also possible to achieve variable-length arguments by using func_num_args(), func_get_arg(), and func_get_args() functions.

So, in all supported versions of PHP (5.5 has been [unsupported for over 5 years](https://www.php.net/eol.php); I hope you're paying someone for long-term-support security patches!), you can define the following function:

```
function example($normalArg, ...$variadicArgs) {
    var_dump($variadicArgs);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
example('normal'); // $variadicArgs = []
example('normal', 1); // $variadicArgs = [1]
example('normal', 1, 2); // $variadicArgs = [1,2]
example('normal', 1, 2, 3); // $variadicArgs = [1,2,3]
```

In ancient versions of PHP before the `...` notation was added, you had to instead declare the function with only the normal arguments, collect *all* the passed arguments by calling [func_get_args](https://php.net/func_get_args), and skip over the "normal" ones. For example:

```
function example($normalArg) {
    $allArgs = func_get_args();
    $variadicArgs = array_slice($allArgs, 1);
    var_dump($variadicArgs);
}
```

So in your case, the function could begin:

```
protected function buildPath($basePath)
{
    $ids = \array_slice(\func_get_args(), 1);
```

---

Later in the function, it is using *array unpacking*. The only way to achieve this in ancient versions of PHP is using [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array), which takes a "callable" (which in simple cases can just be a function name as a string), and an array of arguments to pass to it. Again, you'll need to construct the *full* list of arguments, for instance using `array_merge`:

```
$fixedArgs = [$basePath];
$dynamicArgs = \array_map('\urlencode', $ids);
$allArgs = \array_merge($fixedArgs, $dynamicArgs);
return \call_user_func_array('\sprintf', $allArgs);
```

Or all on one line:

```
return \call_user_func_array('\sprintf', \array_merge([$basePath], \array_map('\urlencode', $ids)]);
```

As it happens, the particular function called here is [sprintf](https://php.net/sprintf), which has a variant called [vsprintf](https://php.net/vsprintf) ("v" for "vector") which takes an array of parameters instead of multiple separate arguments, so for this particular case you can use that:

```
return \vsprintf($basePath, \array_map('\urlencode', $ids));
```

Answer (score 1):

In php `5.5.9` it can be written like this and is called [Variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function):

```php
protected function buildPath($basePath)
    {
        $ids = func_get_args();
        array_shift($ids);
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            if (null === $id || '' === \trim($id)) {
                $msg = 'The resource ID cannot be null or whitespace.';

                throw new \Stripe\Exception\InvalidArgumentException($msg);
            }
        }

        return \sprintf($basePath, ...\array_map('\urlencode', $ids));
    }
```

Comment: I didn't notice either at first, but the function actually uses *both* meanings of `...`, so you'll need to fix the `...\array_map` as well to make it work on ancient PHP.

Comment: I think that is a good solution. Do you know what I would do with the 2nd ellipses?: 

return \sprintf($basePath, ...\array_map('\urlencode', $ids));

Comment: I don't have an idea how to do this in short way as you want, you can always do unpacking by using simple `for`. Or look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684728/php-5-4-17-alternative-for-the-operator